# How can I answer someone that was harsh with me?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, expressions, writing

Someone has been harsh with me in their comments; how can I reply to him?

**My attempts:**

For example can I say :

> - I'm here to learn and that's why I asked too many questions, even if it looks stupid, but you were harsh!
> - I'm here to learn, that's why I asked too many questions, even if its looks stupid and I felt hurt!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without wanting to sound harsh - try proofreading your question: Why do you give the *exact same sentence* twice? Why double exclamation marks? Perhaps capitalize the first letter in a sentence? We will be quite tolerant with beginners here (and edit for you, if necessary), but other Stack Exchange sites might be less tolerant. A general hint for good communication skills: Don't say "*you* did something wrong", say "*I* felt hurt". Changing the pattern helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is not far off - just a few grammar errors.

While you *could* say:

> I'm here to learn, that's why I asked so many questions - even if it looks stupid. But you were harsh.

I'd recommend to change the last part:

> ...But I think your comment was too harsh. or
>   ...But your comment hurt.

The reason: 
The person you are talking to might feel attacked if you say something along the lines of "you did XYZ wrong". Especially if the discussion went for a bit or is heated / emotional. If you state how *you* feel or percieve the situation, the other person can't argue about your feelings.

Comment: here"s the comments : "We can say they are continuous, but it would be a wrong thing to say. Also, nobody said the same x would give sup for both u and v. Also, this is my last comment here."

Comment: Sounds like a mathematical disagreement and a fed-up commenter. But I coudn't say without context. And sorry, I can't solve that for you.

Comment: yes it's mathematical disagreement and i don't like 'Also, this is my last comment here'. but it's okay thanks for ur help